# React dynamic hook name change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I take a button's name from onClick and work out if the button pressed is the correct answer. I want to dynamically change the hook based on this value passed in. I am using react hooks to change the class to display if it's incorrect or correct. Before I used class components and used this:

```
this.setState({
            [button]: 'btn-success',
```

Currently I have something ugly like this:

```
if (button.includes('1')) {
            setBtn1('btn-success');
        } else if (button.includes('2')) {
            setBtn2('btn-success');
        } else if (button.includes('3')) {
            setBtn3('btn-success');
        } else if (button.includes('4')) {
            setBtn4('btn-success');
        }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: (Side note: If you're used to class components, why write a hook instead?)

Comment: How exactly is it supposed to work? Do you need a separate state for each button? What happens after the user clicks an answer? Can they pick a second one? - Note that you can in general do this: `const fns = [fn1, fn2, fn3];` then do `fns[some_var]()` to call one of them.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this is exactly what I needed. I'm new to this so I can't articulate my problems very well. But this worked exactly how I wanted it to!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading this correctly (there is some context missing), you should be able to do this:

```
const [btns, setBtns] = useState({});

// then, in your handler function
setBtns({...btns, [button]: 'btn-success'})
// or (thanks for the comment) as a callback
setBtns((btns)=>({...btns, [button]: 'btn-success'}))
```

You can see the only thing that changes is that you have to set the entire state to a new object which is accomplished by spreading the old state and then setting the new key afterwards.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. But better in general to use the callback form when modifying state based on existing state: `setBtns(btns => ({...btns, [button]: "btn-success"}));`

Comment: I added it as a second option

Answer (score 1):

As [Taxel said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851024/157247), you can use an object in a state member, which would be similar to what you used with class components. That's probably the best approach for what you describe.

If you don't want to do that, you can also do this with individual state members:

```
const buttons = {
    btn1: useState(""), // btn1[0] is the state, btn1[1] is the setter
    btn2: useState(""), // btn2[0] is the state, btn2[1] is the setter
    btn3: useState(""), // ...
    btn4: useState(""), // ...
};

// ...

buttons[button][1]("btn-success");
```

Or slightly more exotically with destructuring:

```
const buttonStates = {};
const buttonSetters = {};
({0: buttonStates.btn1, 1: buttonSetters.btn1} = useState(""));
({0: buttonStates.btn2, 1: buttonSetters.btn2} = useState(""));
({0: buttonStates.btn3, 1: buttonSetters.btn3} = useState(""));

// ...

buttonSetters[button]("btn-success");
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const buttonStates = {};
    const buttonSetters = {};
    ({0: buttonStates.btn1, 1: buttonSetters.btn1} = useState(""));
    ({0: buttonStates.btn2, 1: buttonSetters.btn2} = useState(""));
    ({0: buttonStates.btn3, 1: buttonSetters.btn3} = useState(""));

    const setButton = (button, value) => {
        buttonSetters[button](value);
    };

    return <div>
        <div>
            btn1: {buttonStates.btn1}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-success" onClick={() => setButton("btn1", "btn-success")}/>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-error" onClick={() => setButton("btn1", "btn-error")}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>
            btn2: {buttonStates.btn2}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-success" onClick={() => setButton("btn2", "btn-success")}/>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-error" onClick={() => setButton("btn2", "btn-error")}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <div>
            btn3: {buttonStates.btn3}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-success" onClick={() => setButton("btn3", "btn-success")}/>
                <input type="button" value="Set btn-error" onClick={() => setButton("btn3", "btn-error")}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>;

    buttonSetters[button]("btn-success");
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But without a powerful reason for wanting individual state members for each button, I'd go with the approach [Taxel showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69851024/157247).

Comment: @Dane - My pleasure. It's a bit arcane.  Unless you have a really strong reason for the above, I'd do what Taxel showed (and have, several times). Happy coding!